# Two views next to each other of same height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two views on the top of each other.
My first view is filling up the screen (0dip) and the second view consists of two views (keypad and rl_pointsblock) next to each other.

How can I make the view on the right side the same height as the view on the left side?
I am trying to do this (and you will capture this in the code), the rl_pointsblock view is made of two sub views on the top of each other, and I am trying to make it so that these two views are filling up the space the keypad view is using!

Has someone tried something like this before?

```
<com.exeliumpartners.myclass
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/keypad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">  
            <TableRow>
            </TableRow> 
        </TableLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_pointsblock"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/keypad"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/points_up_layout" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_edges" >
                <TextView/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/points_down_layout" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_edges" >
                <TextView/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linear layout instead of the Relative layout.
In doing so, you now have access to android:layout_weight

Answer (score 1):

Use LinearLayout, don't use RelativeLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/keypad"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_pointsblock"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/points_up_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/points_down_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to change the android:layout_height="match_parent" to wrap_content for the top one and the rl_pointsblock… then it did answer the requirements. Cheers.